# Historically, why is "to" added to the start of every verb? E.g. "to go" "to run"? Why don't we just say "I want run." "I need go."?

Tags: etymology, infinitives

Historically, why is "to" added to the start of every verb? E.g. "to go" "to run"? Why don't we just say "I want run." "I need go." ?

I'm not sure how to make a Google search about this so I came to ask the question on this forum.
(BTW why don't we just say: I'm not sure how make a Google search about this so I came ask the question on this forum.?)

Is it to distinguish what we are saying from commands? E.g. I'm going run ->! I'm going. Run!

Or maybe it distinguishes verbs from nouns? I want Run ->! I want to run.

Comment: It's called the _infinitive_. https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/

Comment: It is possible to find some legitimate idioms, like "I want out (of a scheme, etc.)". You can also say "I'm going running" or "I want washing" - at least in my local dialect.

Comment: It used to be "one run", but then inflation struck!

Comment: @KateBunting And I assume the question is, how did the particle "to" come to be used in forming the infinitive?

Comment: You may be starting in the wrong place. _For I want for to go to Widecombe Fayre_.

Comment: It's a preposition that's been drafted to mark the infinitive verb form (which is otherwise indistinguishable from the present verb form because English lost its verb inflections) in an infinitive clause. Just the same way the preposition _for_ has been drafted to mark the subject noun phrase in an infinitive clause, as in _For him to leave now would be a mistake_. Constructions like _for...to_ that introduce and identify certain types of clauses are called _Complementizers_, and there are several of them in English, like _that_ in _He knows that he's going to flunk._

Comment: The nearly universal use of to with infinitives (to sleep, to dream, etc.) arose in Middle English out of the Old English dative use of to, and it helped drive out the Old English inflectional endings (though in this use to itself is a mere sign, without meaning). https://www.etymonline.com/word/to —- Infinitive - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive

Comment: Hebrew is a really old language and also uses the *to* as a mark of the infinitive. In fact, it's a prefix and also, as in English, serves as the preposition *to me*, *to God*, *to Jerusalem*.

Comment: @TannerSwett I was giving the OP a clue as to where to start looking!